# Is it Possible to load the BackGroundAgent dynamically and make it work?

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-agents

I have a Window phone 8 app and I need to have a BackGroundAgent for this app. I know that we can simply add the reference of background agent project in the main app and it works fine. but I want to load it dynamically in Main app through Assembly.Load() and make it work.

```
    public MainPage()
    {         
        try
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("BackGroundAgent");
        }           
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);             
            return;
        }           
        StartPeriodicAgent();
    }

   private void StartPeriodicAgent()
    {
        periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(periodicTaskName) as PeriodicTask;
        if (periodicTask != null)
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Remove(periodicTaskName);
        }

        periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(periodicTaskName);

        periodicTask.Description = "This demonstrates a periodic task.";

        try
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
        }
        catch (SchedulerServiceException)
        {
        }
    }
```

WMAppManifest.xml

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume" />
  <ExtendedTask Name="TombStoneBackGroundAgent">
    <BackgroundServiceAgent Name="TombStoneAgent" Source="BackGroundAgent.dll" Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Type="BackGroundAgent.ScheduledAgent"/>
  </ExtendedTask>
</Tasks>
```

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work - but why don't you just try it? Or have you tried and gotten an error?

Comment: I tried it and I could see the Backround agent deployed but OnInvoke() is not called at Scheduled Time.

Comment: It worked! My Background dll had a dependency on other dll which also should have been present in the XAP and loaded dynamically.